Grafana Geomap markers not showing up (source is InfluxDB)
Data flow is:
owntracks mobile app -> nodered -> influxDB -> grafana
I connected InfluxDB as a source in my Grafana in order to retrieve some geopositions
It's working in a table:

with query:
SELECT latitude, longitude FROM owntracks
but no markers on a Geomap with same query:
SELECT "latitude", "longitude" FROM "owntracks"

It seems the data type is not what grafana is expecting for a longitude and latitude?
